# How can I pass parameters through a Omniauth/Facebook login request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, parameters, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I integrated the [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) gem with [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). I got sign up and sign in to work, but I can't figure out how to pass additional parameters through to the `facebook` callback method in RegistrationsController, for example the url the user started the sign up process on.

Parameters I include in the initial url (for example, `localhost:3000/auth/facebook?url="url"`) are not passed through to my `facebook` method in my Registrations controller.

**erb link**

```
<%= link_to "fb", facebook_omniauth_path(url: "url") %>
```

**routes**

```
get 'auth/facebook', as: 'facebook_omniauth'
get 'auth/facebook/callback' => 'registrations#facebook'
```

**controller**

```
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

Does anyone know how I can use the `url` parameter in my `facebook` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `omniauth.auth` does not display the additional parameters by default. You need to use `omniauth.params` instead to retrieve `url` value like below.

```
request.env["omniauth.params"]["url"]
```

Comment: There it is! Can I ask where you learned this? I couldn't find anything about this in the docs.

Comment: It is not documented properly. I figured it out by looking into some SO answers.